# How can I protect my SMPS feedback voltage divider from loading effects?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, voltage-divider, feedback

Background: I now have a working switched mode boost converter on a breadboard, working as a 12 Volt DC to 24 Volt DC converter. I was troubleshooting what looked like an output voltage problem when I noticed that my meter was actually just changing the feed back path to the controller IC, causing it to stabilize at around 18.5 Volts; I confirmed this with a x10 probe on a handheld scope.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCkGJn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question then: how does one go about protecting the feedback path from a change in its ratio? Are there any clever tricks, or do I just need to use larger value resistors? What would a pro do?

Comment: Larger value resistors is a good start. Try values x5-10

Comment: Basically, don't touch sensitive feedback circuits like those without using very high impedance probes. Also dont set the feedback resistors too high (keep below 1M ohm) and also read this http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt469/slyt469.pdf

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for that; my google-fu simply wasn't working out.

Comment: no worries! would you like that info collated into an 'answer' that you could accept? And Google-fu is the art of engineering, you'll get it!

Comment: @KyranF,  if you'd be so kind,  I will surely check it off when I see it tomorrow. For the moment, the bed is calling my name. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use higher value resistor values in your divider, to give better power efficiency, and hopefully have less effect on other systems/loading. Don't set your feedback resistance too high though, stay below 1M Ohms.

The probe or pins of a multimeter WILL affect the feedback resistance in parallel with ground, and therefore adjust the output voltage during operation. The best way to see the feedback voltage is to use a very high impedance probe set, which may still affect it a little bit, but much less than standard probe sets.

Further reading on resister dividers and their use in DC-DC converter feedback signals, check this [Texas Instruments Application Note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt469/slyt469.pdf)

Comment: Just another follow up; I roughly quadrupled the total resistance of my divider to around half a meg, and it's working brilliantly. Still need to retweak the ratios because I'm a little high, but whatever.

Comment: Having the voltage a little over is probably better than just under, because under load the voltage will sag anyway. +5% on top of your 24V wont hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a meter (generally 10Mohm input impedance) will *lower* the feedback voltage for a given output (effectively it will reduce the value of your 15 kohm). This in turn will cause the SMPS to need to regulate at a higher output to satisfy the feedback loop.

I doubt that a 10M meter would cause a noticeable difference in the output -- or were you using a lower impedance meter ?

To make the circuit less sensitive, scale *all* feedback resistors lower (e.g. 12k & 1.5k). As noted above, this will waste a little more power.

Comment: Hi, jp. Since this post, I've completed this project and received my diploma. On the count of lowering the resistances, that has experimentally been verified to be a bad idea for the very reasons I was having this problem in the first place. Please read the wonderful TI note that KyranF links.

Comment: No, the TI document basically says that lower resistances are only bad because they reduce efficiency. In most other respects (noise, accuracy, parasitics, etc.) high resistances are bad.

Comment: What you are missing here is that I actually built the thing and have definitively proven that lower resistance makes the output more sensitive to load effects by allowing the feedback network to reach equilibrium at an inappropriate voltage, regardless of any additional duty cycle that might be available to the controller. We aren't talking about thermal noise here - it was a DC level at 24 volts.

Comment: You must be skipping something in your explanation then.
What is the reference voltage for the feedback ? What controller are you using ? Connecting a meter (e.g. resistor) across the 15k ohm will cause the output to increase.

Comment: The system is operating - with the one meter I had as a student, taking a voltmeter reading across the 15k resistance will only ever show the voltage I expect - that's how the controller works, it will change until that node is what it needs to be. But taking the output voltage across the capacitor caused an undesired shift down in the output because the feedback pin reached its fixed setpoint at a lower output voltage. This was, in fact, and not hypothetically, remediated by increasing the total resistance of the divider.